# Can't run Jupyter notebooks over Anaconda on Mac M1

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have a problem with loading Jupyter notebook from my Anaconda Navigator on M1 Mac. When I try to launch `jupyter notebook` I get this error :

> The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10826 "kLSNoLaunchPermissionErr: User doesn't have permission to launch the app (managed networks)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSLaunchWithRunningboard, _LSLine=2508, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fefa8432b50 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fefa8435de0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed with error: 153}}}}}

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an M1 user too. This will not solve the issue, but you can run `jupyter notebook` on Terminal and it will work even though Jupyter Notebook does not load from Anaconda Navigator. If you want Jupyter Notebook to run in a specific environment, simply type `conda activate myenv` and once the environment is activated, type in `jupyter notebook`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually load my jupiter-notebook in vscode, you can give it a try

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also a MacBook M1 user and have run into this problem. Can no longer launch Jupyter Notebook from home screen. Work around on this for me, if you still want to use Anaconda Navigator is to go to the left menu and click on environments, choose the environment and click on the arrow and click on "open with Jupyter Notebook. Ridiculous, but it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).